# iOS - How to play youtube video automatically on UIWebView OR direct with any Video Player?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube, uiwebview

I have a custom cell in which I am loading youtube video and playing. It is working fine. But I want to extract that video thumbnail and add it on UIWebView and remove default play button, So, when user every time up/down tableview, it should not hit youtube URL every time. That's why I want to add video thumbnail and a custom play button **or** if we can use default button then no problem, If user clicks that button video should play without further interaction. What I did yet :
**I extracted videoID + thumbnail** 
 . Now how to do next steps ? Any suggestion will be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
YtbwebView.delegate = self;
        YtbwebView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 300, 600, 340)];
        NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:ytbUrl];
        NSString *htmlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<object width='212' height='172'><param name='movie' value='%@'></param><param name='wmode' value='transparent'></param><embed src='%@'type='application/x-shockwave-flash' wmode='transparent' width='585' height='320'></embed></object>",url,url];
        [YtbwebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:YtbwebView];
```